# ocelot Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path with {everything} is not work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, api-gateway, ocelot

I am using ocelot v17.0.0 to forward my requests to downstream services, with configuration as below it matches only requests with a following path like `/api/route1/1` or `/api/route1/1?key1=value1`:

```
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/route1/{email}/{everything}",
  "ChangeDownstreamPathTemplate": {
    "email": "Claims[email] > value"
  },
  "DownstreamScheme": "http",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 1234
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/route1/{everything}",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
    "GET"
  ]
}
```

But, requests like `/api/route1` or `/api/route1?key1=value1` are not matched with this log:

> UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match Route configuration for upstream path: /api/route1, verb: GET. errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/api/route1, request method: GET

I can handle it with additional config as below:

```
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/route1/{email}/",
  "ChangeDownstreamPathTemplate": {
    "email": "Claims[email] > value"
  },
  "DownstreamScheme": "http",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 1234
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/route1/",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
    "GET"
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to handle both requests with a one route config?